# SVG <image> not displaying

Tags: html, image, svg

I have an `<image>` inside of an `<svg>` that is not displaying. I have checked the SVG spec and several SVG demos. This code should work, but the image does not appear. Any ideas?

```
<svg width="415" height="240">
   <g transform="translate(115, 0)">
      <image href="img/test.png" width="143" height="15" x="0" y="0"></image>
   </g>
</svg>
```

The image href URL is correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `xlink`

`<image xlink:href="img/test.png" width="143" height="15" x="0" y="0"></image>`

Comment: Great, thanks Duo! Wtf is "xlink" by the way? Never come across that prefix, is that vestigial from xml's xpath?

Comment: To tell you the truth I have no idea, perhaps someone with more knowledge about XML/SVG might be able to clarify this because W3's spec on this matter is inescrutable to me.

Comment: For some background on xlink, see e.g http://www.adobe.com/devnet/svg/articles/svg-jon-ferraiolo-interview.html.